# webpack-dev-server get blank screen

Tags: javascript, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Greetings I'm building a MERN stack for the first time and using Webpack  as my build tool. The goal is to have the API's of the app served by Express and the static content(my static dir) and bundles served by webpack-dev-server.

```
Here is my build:
Project is running at http://localhost:8000/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from static
Hash: 0f82642b68722fddb0c7
Version: webpack 3.1.0
Time: 3941ms
           Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
   app.bundle.js  15.4 kB       0  [emitted]         app
vendor.bundle.js  1.35 MB       1  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
  [10] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {1} [built]
  [80] ./node_modules/react/react.js 56 bytes {1} [built]
 [153] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 5.59 kB {1} [built]
 [171] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.61 kB {1} [built]
 [173] ./node_modules/babel-polyfill/lib/index.js 833 bytes {1} [built]
 [209] ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 59 bytes {1} [built]
 [235] ./node_modules/whatwg-fetch/fetch.js 12.7 kB {1} [built]
 [236] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/App.jsx 52 bytes {0} [built]
 [237] ./node_modules/url/url.js 23.3 kB {1} [built]
 [243] ./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {1} [built]
 [245] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 856 bytes {1} [built]
 [284] ./src/App.jsx 655 bytes {0} [built]
 [482] ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js 5.17 kB {1} [built]
 [567] ./src/IssueList.jsx 8.32 kB {0} [built]
 [570] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000 webpack/hot/dev-server react react-dom whatwg-fetch babel-polyfill 88 bytes {1} [built]
    + 556 hidden modules
webpack: Compiled successfully.


My dependencies:
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.29"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
  }


My webpack.config.js file:

    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const path = require('path');


    module.exports = {
        entry: {
            app: './src/App.jsx',
            vendor:['react', 'react-dom', 'whatwg-fetch'],
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
            filename: "app.bundle.js"
        },
        plugins: [
          new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: 'vendor',filename: 'vendor.bundle.js'})
        ],
        module: {
            rules:[
                {
                    test:/\.jsx$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['react','es2015']
                        }
                    }
                },
            ]
        },

        devServer:{
            port: 8000,
                contentBase: '/Users/Angel/WebstormProjects/myMern/static',
                proxy: {
                '/api/*':{
                    target: 'http://localhost:3000',
                }
            }
        }

    };
```

When I open port: 8000 I get a blank screen but all the network traffic is good.... I'm I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: In your `contentBase` directory do you have an `index.html` file that has script tags to your bundle and vendor files ? Have a look at [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)

Comment: yes I do. thank you for asking. the two scripts are inside my body tags. The vendor.bundle.js and then the App.bundle.js.

Comment: Dont use an absolute path for the contentBase. Just do 'static' or 'bin' or something. You won't even see the folder created so it doesn't matter

Comment: Thank you I changed it back to 'static' . Maybe I read the it wrong but the Docs said that was the recommended way.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an index.html to your webpak config, so it can work with it. Try to use [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/README.md) and/or html-loader.

Comment: My index.html file is in the static directory. Isn't that enough? Thank you.

Comment: Not for a webpack-dev-server. Just relaize that webpack dev server is just an instance of express server. That has nothing to do with other server instances like apache/nginx or even file system. It simply copys all files you used in a bundle and than allow you to access them throuth http. That's all - if your bundle has no reference to file, than for webpack it doesn't exist. In webpack dev server there is no such thing as "static dicectory". Webpack is a module bundler, it doesn't care about static whatever..

Comment: If you don't want to use html-webpack-plugin, than consider using something else than module bundler. You may want to use eg. gulp with webpack, or maybe gulp with rollup, or whatever... But html-webpack-plugin will do the magic thing. There is no reason to over-complicate this what so ever..

Comment: Check if you have set the filename to something obscure.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @robbieprevost for the assist. This new configuration worked for me:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/App.jsx',
    vendor: ['react', 'react-dom', 'whatwg-fetch', 'babel-polyfill', 'react-router'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './static'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['app', 'vendor'],
      minChunks: Infinity,
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8000,
    contentBase: 'static',
    proxy: {
      '/api/*': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
      },
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your bundles are build correctly, either by inspecting them manually running `$ webpack` or maybe there are errors/warnings in the `console`, it's likely to get a blank page in case there are build errors and the JS fails to load/parse/execute. Otherwise check the proxy settings or remove them if possible, check them by adding some HTML to your `index.html` manually.

Comment: the manual html worked here I put my build on the top of the original post. Thank you!